# wpf datagrid still hidden scrollbar

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollbar, hidden

I add in code columns to datagrid view.

```
    public List<DateTime> DaysOfMonth { get; set; }

    public static List<DateTime> GetDates(int year, int month)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)) 
                         .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day)) 
                         .ToList(); 
    }


//add to datagrid
            DaysOfMonth = GetDates(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);

            Dps.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Raw material" });
            Dps.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Description" });
            Dps.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Part No" });

            foreach (var d in DaysOfMonth)
            {
                Dps.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = d.ToShortDateString() , FontSize = 14});
            }
```

XAML:

```
    <DataGrid Name="Dps" 
              Margin="2,2,2,2"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

If I have in datagrid for example 30 columns scrollbar is still hidden I don’t why.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on the container the DataGrid is in. If you f.e. have it in a DataGrid the DataGrid just grows and you will not have scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal scrollbar wont show unless you actually have items in your datagrid.

If you'll have scenarios where your DataGrid has no items but your columns are wide enough to require a horizontal scrollbar, instead of working with the ScrollBar properties of the DataGrid itself... I've found it easier to put the DataGrid directly into a ScrollViewer instead.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="2,2,2,2">
    <DataGrid Name="Dps" />
</ScrollViewer>
```